# Expo android createAlbumAsync does not function

Tags: android, expo

I'm currently running the following code:

```
async createPhotoAlbum(currentOrderId, imgAsset) {
  console.log(imgAsset);
  const albumCreated =  await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync(currentOrderId, imgAsset, false);
  console.log(albumCreated);
  return albumCreated
}
```

At albumCreated I get the following error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Could not get all of the requested assets]
```

According to the documentation on Android the file has to be a `file:///`
I've confirmed this is the case imgAsset logs:

```
file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540impactcolor%252Feagle-eye-property-inspections/ImageManipulator/8c22caaa-361f-4fbf-9c60-b98d0d90e964.jpg
```

Any idea why I can't create an album on android?   This works on iphone.